# Why aren't new entries added to the database?

Tags: python, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a flask form and database defined as separate classes. I have a working view function, and the html looks to be rendered properly. When I press the "Submit" button, a new entry should be added to the database, but it isn't. The redirect() works, the render_template() works, everything seems to work except that I can't add to the database.

My flask form (abbreviated version):

```
class CafeForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Cafe Name", [validators.DataRequired()])
    map_url = StringField("Location on Google Maps (URL)", [validators.DataRequired(), validators.URL()])
    img_url = StringField("Image(s) of Cafe (URL)", [validators.DataRequired(), validators.URL()])
    location = StringField("Neighborhood or Village", [validators.DataRequired()])
    has_sockets = SelectField("Device Charging Available?", choices=[("False", "False"), ("True", "True")],
                              validators=[DataRequired()])
    seats = StringField("Approximate Seating Capacity", [validators.DataRequired()])
    coffee_price = StringField("Price of Large Black", [validators.DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

My database model:

```
class Cafes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "cafe"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    map_url = db.Column(db.Text(250), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.Text(250), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.Text(100), nullable=False)
    has_sockets = db.Column(db.Boolean, server_default="false", default=False)
    seats = db.Column(db.Integer)
    coffee_price = db.Column(db.Text(100))
```

My view function:

```
@app.route("/new-cafe", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_cafe():
    form = CafeForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        cafe = Cafes(
            name=form.name.data,
            map_url=form.map_url.data,
            img_url=form.img_url.data,
            location=form.location.data,
            has_sockets=form.has_sockets.data,
            seats=form.seats.data,
            coffee_price=form.coffee_price.data
        )
        db.session.add(cafe)
        db.session.commit()
        # return render_template("cafes.html")
        return redirect(url_for('cafes'))
        print(form.errors)
    return render_template("new-cafe.html", form=form)
```

Finally, the html (using jinja2):

```
<form method="POST" action="/cafes">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.name.label }}
            {{ form.name(size=20) }}
            <br>
            {{ form.map_url.label }}
            {{ form.map_url(size=20) }}
            <br>
            {{ form.img_url.label }}
            {{ form.img_url(size=20) }}
            <br>
            {{ form.location.label }}
            {{ form.location(size=20) }}
            <br>
            {{ form.has_sockets.label }}
            {{ form.has_sockets(size=1) }}
            <br>
            {{ form.seats.label }}
            {{ form.seats(size=20) }}
            <br>
            {{ form.coffee_price.label }}
            {{ form.coffee_price(size=20) }}
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Cafe">
        </form>
```

Comment: Your view function only saves to the database when `form.validate_on_submit()` is true.  What if it isn't?  Your html page doesn't include any form field errors, so you have no idea if the form was valid or not...

Comment: @JohnGordon If I'm thinking about it correctly, then if `form.validate_on_submit()` fails, _nothing_ in the if statement will execute. But the `redirect(url_for("cafes"))` works. I did add form field errors in the template, but I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Yes, that's right, if the validation fails, then the entire if block would be skipped.  You're certain that the `redirect(url_for('cafes'))` is being executed?  You're sure it's not just rendering `new-cafe.html`?